# 【SwiftUI】How to initialize an empty struct

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swift-structs

I need some kind help in SwiftUI.

I have a model below that takes in JSON data.
When I want to initialize it as an empty array, it should be simple, just stating Answers, but how can I initialize it not as an array but an empty single data set.

```
struct Answers: Identifiable, Decodable  {
    let id: Int
    let questionsUsersId: Int
    let reactions: [Reactions]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "questions_id"
        case questionsUsersId = "questions_users_id"
        case reactions = "reactions"
    }

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    self.id = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id) ?? 0
    self.questionsUsersId = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .questionsUsersId) ?? 0
    self.reactions = try container.decodeIfPresent([Reactions].self, forKey: .reactions) ?? [Reactions]()
}


 }
```

I've tried var answer: Answers = Answers( ) but got the errors below:

```
//Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call
//Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'
```

The reason I want to initialize it empty is because I need to hand over the default value of it when the data model is nil. (i.e. what should I write in the xxx?)

```
 @ObservedObject var receiveAnswersViewModel = ReceiveAnswersViewModel()
  //abbreviate
            NavigationLink(destination: AnswerDetailView(answer: receiveAnswersViewModel.answer ?? xxx), isActive: $shouldNavigate) {
                    
                        ForEach(myPageViewModel.answers(forFilter: selectedFilter)?.answers ?? [Answers]()) { answer in
                         
                         AnswerCell(answer: answer)
                                .gesture(TapGesture()
                                                .onEnded({ _ in
                                                    //your action here
                                    self.answersId = answer.answersId
                                    receiveAnswersViewModel.fetchAnswers(answers_id: answersId ?? 0)
                                       }))
                         }
                    }
```

This is what I'm trying to do above: Show several cells using NavigationLink. (Imagine that the cells are tweets.) Press one of the tweets in the list → Call fetchAnswers func in the View Model which takes the pressed tweet id as the argument → Returns the specific tweet detail info→ Put it in the Answer model → Hand it over to the View → Navigate to the Tweet Detail View.

View Model code is below:

```
class ReceiveAnswersViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var answer: Answers?

func fetchAnswers(answers_id: Int){
//abbreviate
self.answer = try JSONDecoder().decode(Answers.self, from: data)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "When I want to initialize it as an empty array, it should be simple, just stating [Answers]()" at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable way is to add a static method to create an empty instance. In this case you have also to add the `init` method

By the way name the struct in singular form, an instance represents likely one `Answer`

```
struct Answer: Identifiable, Decodable  {
    let id: Int
    let questionsUsersId: Int
    let reactions: [Reactions]

    static let example = Answer(id: 0, questionsUsersId: 0, reactions: [])

    init(id: Int, questionsUsersId: Int, reactions: [Reactions]) {
        self.id = id
        self.questionsUsersId = questionsUsersId
        self.reactions = reactions
    }

...
```

Then you can declare

```
var answer = Answer.example
```

Comment: Vadian, thanks a lot. I added the static let example in the struct but got three errors below. 
Could you kindly help me out?

1. Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3 in call
2. Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call
3. Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>, '

Comment: You have to add the standard `init` method. See the edit.

Comment: Vadian, thanks. In that case do I have to delete the current init(from decoder: Decoder)? I need to decode the JSON data and put it in the Answers Model so I wouldn't want to delete it. Currently I'm doing it as the following way. "self.answer = try JSONDecoder().decode(Answers.self, from: data)". If I use standard init, I won't be able to parse the JSON data into the Answers Model. (By the way I also initialize this Answers Model as an array in a different function so I named it Answers, though in this question I initialize it as single data set.)

Comment: You need both `init` methods, so keep `init(from decoder`. If you have an array, then the first item in the array is an *answer* not an *answers*. The plural form is confusing. Look at Standard Library: An array of strings is `[String]` not `[Strings]`.